# Get random string from array in Android and place it in a text view

Tags: android

I have as a small project to create an array of `Name`, `Surname` and `Email` which I have created using xml in the value

This is my xml named `Name` with a String named `names`

```
<resources>
    <string name="names">
        <item>Ivan</item>
        <item>Santiago</item>                    
        .....
    </string>
</resources>
```

This is my XML named Surnames with a String called surnames

```
<resources>
    <string name="surnames">
        <item>Rodríguez</item>
        <item>Gómez</item>
        <item>López</item>
        .....
    </string>
</resources>
```

[image]

```
public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView Nombre,Apellido,Correo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
        //Seteamos las Cajas de Texto
        Nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        Apellido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtApellido);
        Correo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCorreo);
        //Ponemos en Modo de Escucha al Boton
        findViewById(R.id.btnGenerar).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

I want to randomly select names from the XML arrays and display them in a text view.

Comment: Sounds great.  Do you have a problem or question?

Comment: `<string name="nomes">`

Comment: @CzarMatt E created 2 XML one named 'Name' and another 'Surname' I want that by means of a RANDOM, the GENERAR button I autocomplete the text boxes, which are shown in the image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your names in a string array:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="nomes">
        <item>Ivan</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
    ...
</resources>
```

Then use [Random](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html) to get a random name from the array:

```
private String[] names;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nomes);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(names.length);
    String randomName = names[randomIndex];
    yourTextView.setText(randomName);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I'm new to ANDROID and I do not know where to put the code.
You can put it next to my code, please

Comment: Zorry and how do I put it in my text box?

Comment: My god, I get error: c
Unfortunately, youApp has stopped

Comment: What error did you get? To display text in a TextView use setText(). E.g. Nombre.setText(randomName)

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores you should assign your text view first and then use getResources method

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
String[] array = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_array);
String randomString = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I'm new to ANDROID and I do not know where to put the code.
You can put it next to my code, please